# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Array fields must be initialized

Tags: java, arrays, jna

I need to use a c ++ DLL with structs in my program. For this, I use JNA but, when I try to call the struct that contains another struc inside, the exception happens

Following are the codes of the structures:

```
public class SSP_PACKET extends Structure {
    public short packetTime;
    public char PacketLength;
    public char[] packetData;

    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList(new String[]{"packetTime",
                "PacketLength", 
                "packetData"});
    }    
}

public class SSP_COMMAND_INFO extends Structure {
    public byte CommandName;
    public byte LogFileName;
    public byte Encrypted;
    public SSP_PACKET Transmit = new SSP_PACKET();
    public SSP_PACKET Receive = new SSP_PACKET();
    public SSP_PACKET PreEncryptTransmit = new SSP_PACKET();
    public SSP_PACKET PreEncryptReceive = new SSP_PACKET();

    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList(new String[]{"CommandName", 
                "LogFileName", 
                "Encrypted",
                "Transmit",
                "Receive",
                "PreEncryptTransmit",
                "PreEncryptReceive"});
    }
}
```

And the exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Array
>   fields must be initialized    at
>   com.sun.jna.Structure.deriveLayout(Structure.java:1228)   at
>   com.sun.jna.Structure.calculateSize(Structure.java:1097)  at
>   com.sun.jna.Structure.allocateMemory(Structure.java:390)  at
>   com.sun.jna.Structure.ensureAllocated(Structure.java:366)     at
>   com.sun.jna.Structure.ensureAllocated(Structure.java:356)     at
>   com.sun.jna.Structure.size(Structure.java:423)    at
>   com.sun.jna.Structure.size(Structure.java:1075)   at
>   com.sun.jna.Native.getNativeSize(Native.java:1271)    at
>   com.sun.jna.Structure.getNativeSize(Structure.java:2125)  at
>   com.sun.jna.Structure.getNativeSize(Structure.java:2115)  at
>   com.sun.jna.Structure.validateField(Structure.java:1149)  at
>   com.sun.jna.Structure.validateFields(Structure.java:1162)     at
>   com.sun.jna.Structure.(Structure.java:189)  at
>   com.sun.jna.Structure.(Structure.java:182)  at
>   com.sun.jna.Structure.(Structure.java:169)  at
>   com.sun.jna.Structure.(Structure.java:161)  at
>   SSP_COMMAND_INFO.(SSP_COMMAND_INFO.java:5)  at
>   Validator.(Validator.java:28)   at test.main(test.java:10)

Answer (score 2):

The error is rather self explanatory and points to the line number giving you a problem.  Line 5 of your `SSP_COMMAND_INFO` class tries to instantiate an `SSP_PACKET` object, but is failing that step because you haven't initialized the array.  JNA (and thus C) doesn't know the size of the array or how much memory to reserve.

Your `public char[] packetData;` needs to be initialized to a new array length, e.g.,

```
public char[] packetData = new char[255];
```

(Obviously rather than 255 you need to consult your API to see what the actual array size is.)

Another important note is that it is very unlikely that Java's `char` type is what you want here.  If you're mapping a C header file with `char` you want to replace it here with `byte`.  I'm guessing you really want:

```
public byte PacketLength;
public byte[] packetData = new byte[255];
```

As a final note, it is unnecessary to initialize the nested structures within your `SSP_COMMAND_INFO` structure as you have with `new SSP_PACKET()`.  JNA does this for you automatically.